What does $\mathscr{C}\mathscr{B}(X,\rho)$ mean in the context of iterated function systems?
I am reading an article titled Infinite Iterated Function Systems (1994) by Henning Fernau, and I have trouble understanding what the author means by the object $\mathscr{C}\mathscr{B}(X,\rho)$, when $(X, \rho)$ is a complete metric space. The first instance in the article is presented in the picture and at least I cannot deduce from the context what is the precise definition of $\mathscr{C}\mathscr{B}(X,\rho)$.
Picture:


The definition is given at the top of page 80:

$\varrho_H$ is also a metric on the collection of all non-empty closed and bounded sets $\mathscr{CB}(X,\varrho)$.

That is, if $X$ is a set with metric $\varrho$ (that is, if $(X,\varrho)$ is a metric space), then this is the set of all subsets of $X$ which are bounded with respect to $\varrho$, and which are closed in the topology induced by $\varrho$.
